# C# - HorizontalScroll for Form Keeps Resetting to Zero

Tags: c#, winforms

I know I'm missing something stupid here. I'm trying to set up a form that has no visible scrollbars, but still allows scrolling via custom buttons/controls.

I set up a blank new WinForms project, put a random user control in a position where it extended past the boundaries of the form - something I could scroll to.

I then set up a button (just for testing purposes for now) for scrolling right on click like this:

```
private void btnScrollRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.HorizontalScroll.Value += 10;
}
```

When I run this and I click on the button, the form shifts / scrolls for a split second, but then instantly resets the HorizontalScroll.Value back to 0, and I'm back to the original view.

Now, if I enable the AutoScroll property, then this same button works just fine - it scrolls as expected, but I end up getting a visible horizontal scrollbar, and I have yet to find a good way of hiding it. I've tried setting HScroll to false, I've tried setting HorizontalScroll.Visible to false, but neither works.

I've read through this:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6b9c2c72-e91a-40f0-a835-c12328490c0c/how-to-scroll-without-a-scrollbar-or-make-scrollbar-invisible?forum=winforms

...and there are some options in there, but I feel like I'm probably just missing something basic. Additionally, everything seems inverted - people say that when you set AutoScroll, you can't change anything programmatically, but this is the opposite of what I'm seeing.

Before I go down a path of clever ways to "trick" the scrollbar into hiding or go about forcing the scrollbar to do it some other weird way, does anyone have any advice on the PROPER way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following code to work for me:

```
    int sc = 0;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sc += 10;
        this.HorizontalScroll.Value = sc;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = true;
        this.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 500; //Calculate this value
    }
```

It only works if a control extends beyond the form's limits and it scrolls until the control's and form's edges meet.

It's important that you calculate how far the control extends and set the maximum scroll value to greater that that, otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: This works. Apparently, the += operator does not work when applied directly to HorizontalScroll.Value. Setting a specific value with the = does work. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed while debugging that it often takes a few executed statements before the internal value actually updates, after you set a new value into it. Really odd.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can make it work.

First, add the following snippet in your form `Load` event:

```
this.AutoScroll = true;
this.AutoScroll = false;
```

Looks like it doesn't make any sense, but the first line forces the form to correctly calculate the virtual scrollable rectangle.

Then you need to manipulate `AutoScrollPosition` and remember to negate the values (don't ask me why, I have no idea like the author the link you followed)

```
private void btnScrollRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-AutoScrollPosition.X + 10, -this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
}
```